# How to properly initialize the JSON store in Worklight 6.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I am attempting to initalize the IBM Worklight JSON store as below:

```
//JSONStore jsonStoreCollection metadata
var jsonStoreCollection = {};

//JSONStore jsonStoreCollection metadata
var COLLECTION_NAME = 'people';

function wlCommonInit(){


    // Create empty options to pass to
    // the WL.JSONStore.init function
    var options = {};

    //Define the collection and list the search fields
    jsonStoreCollection[COLLECTION_NAME] = {
        searchFields : {name: 'string'},
    };


    //Initialize the JSON store collection
    WL.JSONStore.init(jsonStoreCollection, options)
    .then(function () {
        console.log("Successfully Initialized the JSON store");
    })
    .fail(function (errorObject) {
        console.log("JSON store init failed :( ");
    });

}
```

But when I run this in my android emulator the logcat gives me the "JSON store init failed" message. And the following error:

```
[wl.jsonstore {"src":"initCollection", "err":-2,"msg":"PROVISION_TABLE_SEARCH_FIELDS_MISMATCH","col":"token","usr":"jsonstore","doc":{},"res":{}}
```

This implementation seems to be very much what is outlined in the documentation, however I cannot get it to initialize.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried running the JSONStore sample as-is? http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/JSONStoreAPIBasicsProject.zip

Comment: Yes, I have also read both PDF documents from the samples page. You can probably see that this code snippet is very similar to what is in the sample.

Comment: I found my problem. I had previously created a JSON store with the same name but with different initialization variables on the same Android emulator. After uninstalling the Worklight application the JSON store initialization was fine. So if anyone encounters a similar problem when code seems ok.. try uninstall.

Comment: You should probably write this as an answer rather than a comment. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation with the error codes is [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.dev.doc%2Fdevref%2Fr_jsonstore_errorcodes.html).

> -2 PROVISION_TABLE_SEARCH_FIELDS_MISMATCH
>
> Search fields are not dynamic. It is not possible to change search fields without calling
> the destroy method or the removeCollection method in the WL.JSONStore
> class before calling the init method with the new search fields. This
> error can occur if you change the name or type of the search field.
> For example: {key: 'string'} to {key: 'number'} or {myKey: 'string'}
> to {theKey: 'string'}.

No need to uninstall the application, just follow the documentation and handle that error case by calling `removeCollection` or `destroy`. For example:

```
WL.JSONStore.init(...)
.then(function () {
  //init was successful
})
.fail(function (error) {
  //check for -2
  //call removeCollection or destroy
  //re-init with new search fields
});
```

You can always [submit a feature request](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014907906&ps=25) to make this easier.

Comment: Thanks cnandreu. This is a very informative and helpful answer.

Comment: I dont think we can removeCollection without calling init ?

Comment: @SachinThapa is correct: removeCollection only works on a Collection handle which we don't get since init isn't working. Only workaround I can think of is to init with the old set of searchfields, then remove the collection and init it with the new search fields.

Answer (score 0):

If you have previously created a JSON store with the same name but with different initialization variables. You must uninstall the application.

After uninstalling you can re-deploy the application to the device and the JSON store will initialize as expected.

Since discovering this, I have seen the issue a couple more times as I made changes to the configuration of my JSON store in my Worklight application.

Comment: You don't have to uninstall it. In your case, you are trying to initialize it with different search fields, which cannot be changed after initialization. But if you want to change them, you have to first remove the collection from the store (http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc%2Fhtml%2Frefjavascript-client%2Fhtml%2FJSONStoreInstance.html&path%3D0_9_0_0_1_0_15) and then  initialize it again. Errors are explained here: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/r_jsonstore_errorcodes.html

Comment: @Daniel Gonzalez, You have to uninstall it (or wipe user data). I am just attempting to re-deploy my apk to the device, which is not a problem with native applications.  With regular android deployments you can change something relating to your storage options http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html in your code and redeploy to the device and just like magic, the storage is updated as you would expect. With worklight, the previous deployment persists and becomes problematic. I am NOT trying to initalize the json store twice with from the same deployment.