# joining two collections in json store

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

Is it possible to join two collections in JSONStore?

I want to access data from the given two collections in the json store one of which has a foreign key.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing equivalent to a `join` in Relational Databases for JSONStore. However, like Namfo said in the other answer, you may take advantage of `additionalSearchFields` for this use case. It allows you to index values that are not part of the data being stored. For example, if you have a `order` collection and are storing objects like `{item: 'knife'}` you could have an additional search field for `customer_id` which references an `id` search field in the `customer` collection. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26986204/186909) is a post that explains additional search fields.

Answer (score 1):

JSONSTORE does not have the ability to combine collections. However, you can use a common index between the two collections to access relevant data. For instance, order_id search field can be shared between the customer collection and order collection.

Comment: you can use a common index between the two collections to access relevant data..  Can you please write the syntax for your answer.

Comment: I took the liberty of creating a blog post about this matter. You can visit it [here](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/02/24/working-jsonstore-collections-join/)