# How to join two collections in a json store?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I am working on IBM Worklight. I need to access data from two collections. Is there any solution for joining the 2 collections and get the required fields ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [joining two collections in json store](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28408301/joining-two-collections-in-json-store)

Answer (score 0):

JSONSTORE does not have the ability to combine collections.

However the follow blog post details one way to achieve this: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2015/02/24/working-jsonstore-collections-join/

1. Create a collection:

   ```
   var OrdersCollection = {
         orders: {
           searchFields: {
             order_id: 'integer',
             order_date: 'string'
           },
           additionalSearchFields: {
             customer_id: 'integer'
           }
         }
   };
   var CustomerCollection = {
         customers: {
             searchFields: {
                 customer_name : 'string',
                 contact_name : 'string',
                 country : 'string'
             },
             additionalSearchFields : {
                 customer_id : 'integer'
             }
           }
       };
   ```
2. Add data using additional search fields:

   ```
   var data = [
                           {order_id : 462, order_date : '1-1-2000'},
                           {order_id: 608, order_date : '2-2-2001'},
                           {order_id: 898, order_date : '3-3-2002'}
                           ];
               var counter = 0;
               var q = async.queue(function (task, callback) {
                   setTimeout(function () {
                       WL.JSONStore.get('orders').add(task.data, {additionalSearchFields: {customer_id: task.customer_id}});
                       callback(++counter);
                   },0);
               },1);
               for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                q.push({data : data[i], customer_id: i+1}, function(counter){
                    console.log("Added Order Doc " + counter);
                });
               }
           q.drain = function(){
               setTimeout(function() {
                   console.log("Finished adding order documents");
                   WL.JSONStore.get("orders").findAll({filter : ["customer_id", "order_id", "order_date"]})
                       .then(function (res) {
                           ordersCollectionData = res;
                           document.getElementById("orders").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(res, null, "\t");
                       })
                        .fail(function (err) {
                               console.log("There was a problem at " + JSON.stringify(err));
                       });
               },0);
           };
   ```
3. Find the documents to merge:

   ```
   WL.JSONStore.get('orders').findAll({filter : ['customer_id', 'order_id', 'order_date']})
                       .then(function (res) {
                           ordersCollectionData = res;
                       });
   ```
4. Merge

   ```
   var shared_index = 'customer_id';
   var mergedCollection = [];
   mergedCollection =_.merge(customerCollectionData, ordersCollectionData, function(a, b){
           if(_.isObject(a) && (a[shared_index] == b[shared_index])) {
               return _.merge({}, a, b);
           }
   });
   ```